# Program finding product of two numbers

Tags: c++, operators

In this program what is the null case condition I have to put into it when the input is null so that the program in this case

```
//*product of two no.s*//

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double   firstnumber,secondnumber,productoftwonumbers;
    cout<< "Enter two numbers :";
    cin>> firstnumber>>secondnumber;
    productoftwonumbers=firstnumber*secondnumber;
    cout<< "Product ="<<productoftwonumbers<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Had you finished writing your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what your asking is finding out if there are no 0's in the input then here's the solution:

Add this after `cin>> firstnumber>>secondnumber;`

```
if(firstnumber == 0 || secondnumber == 0) return 1;
```

If you're looking for something else we need a better explanation.